# Installing Embedded RTOS in VM ware

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, rtos, iso-image

can RTOS like Nucleus and Zephr  be installed in VM ware

Is it possible to install in VM ware. I like to learn RTOS and if there is any smaller version of some RTOS that can be easy to learn then that will be great. and do They have image file like iso or do I need to compile the code with make

System info
Model name:                      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Architecture:                    x86_64

Comment: A few years ago, I ran QNX Neutrino RTOS under VMware WS.   I am aware of a couple more - such as OnTime RTOS-32 - that also worked under VMware WS.   Would be very surprised if Nucleus could be hosted on VMware WS, however it might work with ESXi-Arm Fling.  Zephr might work on VMware WS as a number of x86 boards are supported.

Comment: Consider running an RTOS in QEMU instead.  Although specifically for FreeRTOS the instructions at https://www.freertos.org/install-and-start-qemu-emulator/ are pretty generic and should work for any appropriately linked and targeted elf file.  It also has the advantage of emulating a processor of the kind you are more likely to find in an embedded system.  Might be easier to just buy a cheap dev-board though - then you get hardware and peripherals and can connect additional I/O.  STM32 Nucleo boards for example are less than $20 and include hardware debug interfaces, for IoT look at ESP32.